# Mandrill blacklist through api

Tags: email, mandrill

I'm trying to create an unsubscribe button in my app which will do the same thing as the unsubscribe link in a Mandrill sent email. I can use the rejects/add.json [endpoint](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/rejects.JSON.html), however there is no option to specify the sender email. If I blacklist the recipient's email address this way, it will block all emails to that recipient and thus not work the same way as the unsubscribe link included in the email. Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Mandrill documentation, https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583017-Can-I-add-an-automatic-unsubscribe-link-to-Mandrill-emails-:

If a recipient clicks the generated link, the message status is changed to Unsubscribed and the recipient's address is added to the Rejection Blacklist in your Mandrill account.

Comment: I'm trying to build a button in my app, not add a link in the email

Comment: I'm addressing your dislike for the "blacklist." According to Mandrill's documentation, the unsubscribe is adding to rejection blacklist.

Comment: Ah I see, yeah but there's a difference and this is my problem. So when you click on the unsubscribe link on the email, Mandrill will add it to the blacklist but it'll record the sender address. So you can send emails to the same recipient with different sender addresses and they will go through (not get rejected). If you add the recipient's email address to the blacklist through the api, all emails to that recipient will get rejected regardless of the sender address. I was hoping someone knew of a work around for this, maybe something not documented in their api.

Comment: What about adding the sub account to the API call when doing the add to blacklist?